# Why this nested css code does not work?

Tags: css

If I have something like the code below I would expect my link to be in red color with large fonts, it does not work, however.

```
.footer {
  text-align: center;
}

.footer a {
  color: red;
  font-size: 32px;
}
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/avUT4/

I don't understand. I'm not good at css but why this code does not work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is some strange character in front of the `.footer a` rule. Try copying the code to [jsbin.com](http://jsbin.com/isiyut/1/) and you'll see it marked by a red dot. This happens to me a lot when copying from jsfiddle. If the char is removed, all is good.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/avUT4/12/) is your fiddle, without that character.

Comment: I'd rather say, it's a jsfiddle problem. Happens all the time if you copy from jsfiddle.

Comment: It's called a [Byte Order Mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) (Here it is when it's URL Encoded: %EF%BB%BF)

Comment: @Yoshi no man, it's Web Essentials 2012 for visual studio. It compiles LESS code to CSS and I wondered what is wrong with it since it looks correct but it's not.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell you have a garbage character somewhere. I rewrote it and it's fine.

```
.footer
{
 text-align:center;   
}

.footer a
{
 color:red;
 font-size:32px;    
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/avUT4/10/

Comment: Yeah, I think that's what I discovered through a different route.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a bug in jsfiddle. If you just define:

```
a {
  color: red;
  font-size: 32px;
}
```

It works. Then if you add .footer (just type it back in before "a"), it works still, but it won't work from the start point when ".footer a" is defined.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
.footer {
  text-align: center;
}

.footer a:link, a:active {
  color: red;
  font-size: 120px;
}
```

​